# Mat-Table sort header not rendering

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement a material table with sortable headers and after following tutorials, I have the following:

componenent file:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="quotes" matSort matSortActive="idCpQuote" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="idCpQuote">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID. </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let quote"> {{quote.idCpQuote}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

</mat-table>

<mat-paginator [length]="total" [pageSize]="20" [pageSizeOptions]="[20, 50, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```

in the component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { QuoteService } from '@app/services/quote.service';
import { first, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { QuoteDataSource } from '@app/services/quote.datasource';
import { QuoteResolver } from '@app/services/quote.resolver';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { QuoteListMeta } from '@app/models/quote.list.meta';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-quotes-list',
    templateUrl: './quotes-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./quotes-list.component.scss'],
    providers: [ QuoteService ]
})

export class QuotesListComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

    quoteListMeta: QuoteListMeta;
    quotes = null;
    displayedColumns = ['idCpQuote', 'name', 'email', 'dateAdd'];
    dataSource: QuoteService;
    total: number;

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private quoteService: QuoteService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.data.subscribe((data) => {
            this.total = data.quoteListMeta.total;
        });
        this.dataSource = this.quoteService;
        this.dataSource.getQuotes('', 'asc', 0, 20).subscribe(
            response => {
                this.quotes = response;
            }
        );
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);

        this.paginator.page
            .pipe(
                tap(() => this.loadQuotesPage())
            )
            .subscribe();
    }

    loadQuotesPage() {
        this.dataSource.getQuotes('', 'asc', this.paginator.pageIndex, this.paginator.pageSize).subscribe(
            response => {
                this.quotes = response;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Material module is already imported in my app.module.ts.

The table renders as expected and so does the pagination, however the sort arrows simply do not render at all.

I just cannot see what I may be doing wrong.

Musaffar

Comment: I actually had this error before. I got it to work again when I just removed everything and started over again by copying the example from [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/examples). They also provide a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/pderdkmlddv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsort-overview-example.ts)

Comment: thanks, but i'm not in a position to start over again, too far in

Comment: Add this.quotes.sort = this.sort;  in ngOnInit() and ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: @MahanteshGowdaPatil what does quotes refer to?  It cannot recognise the name so I tried this.quotes (which is what holds the response data, list of quotes) but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Eventually discovered that by rebuilding the app using "ng build"  solved the problem even though originally the app was being recompiled on each change using ng serve --open, that wasn't enough for my case.

Hope this helps if anyone runs into the same issue.